# Pylint vs. flake8 hanging indentation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, flake8, coding-style

I was using only `flake8` to quick-check my Python 3 code before I noticed `pylint`.

In a project of mine, I have the following code:

```
def strace(self):
    """Dumps a stack trace to a file."""
    try:
        with NamedTemporaryFile(
                'w', prefix=self._file_prefix, suffix='.stacktrace',
                dir=STRACE_DIR, delete=False) as tmp:
            tmp.write(format_exc())
```

According to `flake8` I indented this correctly, since less indentation

```
def strace(self):
    """Dumps a stack trace to a file."""
    try:
        with NamedTemporaryFile(
            'w', prefix=self._file_prefix, suffix='.stacktrace',
            dir=STRACE_DIR, delete=False) as tmp:
            tmp.write(format_exc())
```

will cause an error:

```
homie/api/interface.py:300:5: E129 visually indented line with same indent as next logical line
```

However `pylint` complains about the former style while accepting the latter.

```
C:299, 0: Wrong hanging indentation (remove 4 spaces).
                    'w', prefix=self._file_prefix, suffix='.stacktrace',
                |   ^ (bad-continuation)
C:300, 0: Wrong hanging indentation (remove 4 spaces).
                    dir=STRACE_DIR, delete=False) as tmp:
                |   ^ (bad-continuation)
```

According to PEP8, the former style should be correct.
So how do I configure `pylint` to accept the former indentation style?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Pylint: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/741#issuecomment-288114959